# Reading json data through subscription to service method in Angular

Tags: json, angular, http, subscription

I have gone through other similar topics but nothing worked for me.

**Players.service.ts**

```
 constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

     getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('../../assets/players.json')
            .map((res: any) =>  this.players = res.json() )
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw( 'error', error));
    }
```

**Player.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.playersService.getJSON().subscribe((players: any[]) => {
    this.players = players; console.log('players ', this.players);
},
     error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

**Player.component.html**

```
<app-player-item *ngFor="let player of players"
</app-player-item>
```

and players.JSON

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "surname": "xxxxx",
            "city": "xxxxx",
            "ranking": "12",
            "email": "xxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
            "photo": "assets/images/sk.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sultan Mehmed",
            "level": "Advanced",
            "victories": "18",
            "goalsScored": "23",
            "gamesPlayed": "29",
            "email": "smehmed@ecovadis.com",
            "photo": "assets/images/sm.jpg"
        },
         {....}
         ]
}
```

Should work but i get an errors of:

> - 'Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of    type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>     Arrays.'
> - Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe'    of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>     'unsubscribe' of    undefined

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the data you are expecting from: `this.http.get('../../assets/players.json')`. Also note that `Http` has been superseded by [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) so you no longer have to extract the json from the response.

Comment: How is the player's property defined? Is `this.players` typed as an array?

Comment: i updated my question above with the .json data type ,
yes, I am defining players = any[]   in player.component.ts

Comment: i updated errors i am getting after the correcting res.json()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your service `getJson()`, `this.players = res.json()` not `res.json`

Your other problem is ngFor only works with arrays so  either in your JSON file make it an actual array or in your logic define the array properly.

I.E.

```
getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('../../assets/players.json')
            .map((res: any) => res.json() )
            .map(json => this.players = json['players'])
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw( 'error', error));
```

essentially the first map transforms your json to json object, the second takes the json and grabs the values under `players` key from your json file and maps it to your variable `this.players`

Comment: you're ritght but after I change res.json to res.json() i am still getting 2 errors: 
(1) Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
(2) Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Comment: You need to change your type definition in the same getJSON method to return an array of players

Comment: Mike can you be more explicit please ? do you mean change getJSON(): Observable<any> ? if so change it to what  instead . because this is indeed an Observable.